# MongoID + Rails with Inheritence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, model, mongoid

**Hi**

As I read in manual inheritance for models based on mongo is available. But if I inheritence a model, when saving, he goes to document named by inheritence root name.

i.e.

```
class Base
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :enabled, type: Boolean, default: true
end

class Message < Base
  attr_accessible :name , :description
end

class Event < Base
  field :description, type: String
end
```

When Im performing create on Message and Event both goes to document named base

All I wan to do is store Message model i message document and similar for Event but keep inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a collection for each model

```
class Message < Base
  store_in collection: :messages

  attr_accessible :name , :description
end

class Event < Base
  store_in collection: :events

  field :description, type: String
end
```

Comment: I can not set it with store_in :name it gives me an error... acceptable way to do this is define "store_in collection: name" but then both Message and Event still saves to that same document but this time name of that document depends of which Model define it later... in my case was it a Event...

Comment: Ah, yeah, it was syntax for mongoid 2.x. Hm, let me think about your comment.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, i think store_in is only available in latest mongoid. in mongoid 2 there is no way to store the child documents in different collection. All will be stored under Base collection with _type attribute referring the child classes